# How do I figure out what notification daemon is running?

Tags: notification, i3-wm

I just installed i3wm after messing around with xmonad for a bit and I noticed that I'm receiving desktop notifications, like from Slack for example.

I thought that i3 came with a notifications daemon like it comes with a statusbar and tray, but that doesn't appear to be the case. I don't remember installing one.

How do I figure out what notification daemon is running so I can configure it?

Currently running Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Does https://faq.i3wm.org/question/4062/which-notification-tool-is-i3-using-by-default.1.html have any hints?

Comment: I checked that thread and poked around a bit - it appears to be Dunst. shows up in `ps aux | grep dunst` and responds to `notify send "TEST "TEST"`

so I think that settles that half of the question :-)

Comment: @EnricoTuveraJr Thanks for sharing - I'm new to lubuntu and i3 (coming from dwm) I wasn't sure the notifications were part of i3 or separate. It was killing me as I'm using Ctrl-` (aka ctrl-grave in dunst config) as a meta in tmux and apparently Dunst has precedence, so whenever there is a notification in the dunst history, my tmux stopped working. Now I know what it is - I fixed it in the configuration. Thanks!